# JavaScript: On Firefox mousemove is triggered when resizing window

Tags: javascript, firefox, mousemove, pointerlock

When I'm on Firefox, canvas calls `requestPointerLock` and I'm pressing F11 for fullscreen - I see that event `mousemove` is being triggered. This makes some things to move which must be static because mouse is not moving.

I tried to create a demo, but I get error `Blocked pointer lock on an element because the element's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-pointer-lock' permission is not set.`

So here is a code example which you can read at least.

HTML part:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

JavaScript part:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  canvas.requestPointerLock = canvas.requestPointerLock    ||
                              canvas.mozRequestPointerLock ||
                              canvas.webkitRequestPointerLock;

  if (canvas.requestPointerLock)
      canvas.requestPointerLock();
}, false);


document.addEventListener("pointerlockchange",    plChange, false);
document.addEventListener("mozpointerlockchange", plChange, false);


function plChange(e) {
  var controlEnabled = (document.mozPointerLockElement ===    canvas ||
                        document.webkitPointerLockElement === canvas ||
                        document.pointerLockElement ===       canvas);

  if (!controlEnabled) {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
  }
}


function mouseMove(e) {
    // This is being executed on window resize
    console.log(e.movementY);
}
```

As a result, when window is going fullscreen (and Firefox does it slooowly) - I get **e.movementY** printed in a console and value is not **0** always.

The question is how can I prevent this Firefox "feature" so that mouse move event is not being triggered?

Comment: Do you have an order in which these events are fired? If the resize event comes before the mousemove, there's an easy way to work around this, but if not, mitigating the situation would be a bit trickier.

Comment: Btw: You should turn `canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');`into `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');`. In the first case you'd create a property of the `window`object whereas the second generates a variable. I'd also strongly recommend that you precede all of your JavaScript with `'use strict';` so that errors of this type throw an error when encountered.

Comment: @Robidu, if I add **console.log('resize')** to the additional `window.onresize` function - in a console I see 'resize' at first, then '3', then '4', then '6', then '10', then 'resize' again, then numbers again and so on. So probably resize event is first, but they switch each other later

Comment: Yupp. also discovered this. I have generated a test case to see what's actually going on, however, although I manage to skip many spurious `mousemove` events, some still get through. I need to figure out what's going on - and I have already found out what is actually causing the events to fire in the first place. An explanation is going to follow once I can provide a proper answer on how to mitigate this.

Comment: O.k., found a viable workaround. However, I had to do some retooling with your JavaScript to get things done...

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to mitigate the problem. Unfortunately there's no viable solution that could actually fix the problem, because whenever Firefox resizes its window, the mouse is somehow dragged along so that the pointer's position relative to the top left corner remains unchanged. However, since it moves across the screen, a spurious `mousemove` event is triggered.

A way to mitigate this is adding a `resize` handler to the window object to check whether a window resize is taking place - and if so, set a flag and use it to have the mouse move handler bail out. Unfortunately you cannot just reset this flag when the mouse move fires, because you would still get occasional spurious `mousemove` events. Instead you have to set off a timeout that eventually resets the flag when you can be relatively certain that the browser window has been completely resized.

I managed to get that done with my test case which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>canvas Test Case</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-color: silver;
  }

canvas {
  background-color: white;
  }
</style>
<script type="application/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
'use strict';

var canvas;
var this_timeout = null;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (p_event) {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  document.addEventListener("click", function (p_event) {
    canvas.requestPointerLock = canvas.requestPointerLock    ||
                                canvas.mozRequestPointerLock ||
                                canvas.webkitRequestPointerLock;

    if (canvas.requestPointerLock)
        canvas.requestPointerLock();
    }, false);

  document.addEventListener("pointerlockchange",    plChange, false);
  document.addEventListener("mozpointerlockchange", plChange, false);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function (p_event) {
// Use this handler to set a flag that a resize event is taking place.
// Using the timeout ID actually hits two birds with one stone: It serves as a
// flag that a resize is actually taking place, plus it allows us to reset the
// timeout if it hasn't expired when another one fires.
    if(this_timeout)
      clearTimeout(this_timeout);
    this_timeout = setTimeout(function () { this_timeout = null; }, 250);
    console.log('Resizing...'); }, true);
  }, false);

function stoppedResize() {
// If the timeout expires, reset the timeout id to show that we are done resizing.
  this_timeout = null;
  }

function plChange(p_event) {
  var controlEnabled = (document.mozPointerLockElement ===    canvas ||
                        document.webkitPointerLockElement === canvas ||
                        document.pointerLockElement ===       canvas);

  if (!controlEnabled) {
    console.log('Disabling mouse tracker...');
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
  } else {
    console.log('Enabling mouse tracker...');
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
  }
}

function mouseMove(p_event) {
// Check whether there's a timeout running. If yes, just bail out...
  if(this_timeout)
    {
    console.log('Skipping...');
    return;
    }

  console.log('Mouse movement detected!');
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>canvas Test Case</h1></header>
<main>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" />
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

By doing this you can easily mitigate this problem. Unfortunately it's not the clean solution that I would have preferred, but given the cirumstances, this is the best way to deal with the problem that I could come up with.

As for your other question, I guess you wanted to post an example here on SO? If yes, I think that you have run into some restrictions imposed on the code. Since everything seems to take place in an `iframe`, I guess that certain actions have been disallowed. Attaching certain event handlers is obviously affected.